# Changing sound waves in-place: frequency and amplitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I'm trying to make some changes to a sound frequency and amplitude in place. I am currently getting the sound data, but whenever I try multiplying it by a value, for example to change amplitude, I get a lot of noise. I was wondering how to do that in a clean way. I need to loop through the data because the changes in frequency and amplitude rely on user input (I'll later make changes according to hand position using a webcam). With this current code, my input file had a single channel. I am not sure why, but in "getNewWave", if I change it to np.int16, the audio gets noise as well. Thanks!!

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import numpy as np

def getNewWave(data):

    newdata = np.frombuffer(data, np.int8)
    #make some changes to amplitude and frequency
    return newdata

def main():

    CHUNK = 1024

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Missing input wav file. File must have single channel")
        sys.exit(-1)

    wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    while data != '':
        stream.write(getNewWave(data))
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

main()
```